# page ranking on search engines result

Tags: optimization, search-engine, pagerank

I have a question that I need to have answer for ...

I have built a website, now I need to have it appear on Google, yahoo and other websites on the first page of the search result depending on some keywords that I have ...

I would like to know how I can achieve this. Is there somethings that I need to alter the code? .htaccess?

Thanks all.

Comment: http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/www.google.com/sv//webmasters/docs/search-engine-optimization-starter-guide.pdf

if some of your webpages can cover these keyword have them in the title tag, but dont put too much in there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a google page rank algorithm for example here: http://phpir.com/pagerank-in-php. It's basically a marcov chain, a traversal of a matrix that gives the probability of moving to any state from any other state, with the total probabilities for the destinations from any given page adding up to 1. When you have only 2 probabilities is like having an inverted mask of the starting edge or the first probability. It would be n*n/2-1 of edges.

Comment: Thanks David, but I'm not asking about how it is calculated ... yet I'm asking for how to make my website ranked in Google!